# How are real-world products modelled?

Tags: data, design-patterns, design

In Salesforce you define an object with a strongly typed set of properties and Salesforce will give you list views, details pages and create pages for free. By "reflecting" over the property types, it knows to render the appropriate type of UI element and apply the appropriate validation. sObjects have per property validity and per-object validitity and the forms, validation and so forth are all integrated together so users can *configure* their way to a working application rather than write code. Most of the time.

In my domain, selling software and associated services, my real-world products don't have prices. The price of a product depends on a lot of factors such as:

1. Product configuration options (of which there are about 25)
2. Who's doing the selling (e.g. partner or direct)
3. Who's doing the buying (Customers in different sectors and geographies pay differently)

My question is really about modelling.

I think of a (Salesforce) Product as goods or services I can sell.

I think of a (Salesforce) Opportunity as a chance to sell one-or-more Products.

I think of a Product Option as variations on the Product, e.g.

1. Size: Small, Medium, Large
2. Color: Red, Green, Yellow, Blue
3. Capacity: 10oz, 16oz
4. Class: Lite, Standard, Enterprise
5. Feature selection: Feature A chosen, Feature B not chosen, Feature C chosen.

I should be able to sell more than one Product/Service per Opportunity.

I should be able to look at the detail of an Opportunity and see what is being proposed. Not necessarily the price, but the detail of what we're offering the customer. There should be enough "context" with an Opportunity and its detail that I should be able to produce a quote, though I regard a quote as something separate to an Opportunity and its detail.

In salesforce (and probably other DB systems, you have 3 choices for modelling products with wildly different attributes.

Option 1:

Each Product gets its own Custom Object where the properties on the custom object are individually tailored to the requirements of that product.

Option 2:

A single Product object (definition) is used for all products. The properties of a Product are the sum total of all attributes of all products and there is a discriminator property used to differentiate instances of Product from one another. Not all properties of Product are used all the time; Product A might only use the first 10 properties, Product B might use the next 20, and Product C the last 15.

Option 3:

Properties of Product are stored as name value pairs. A dictionary defines Product Properties and each property has a foreign key back to the Product it relates to. By definition, key-value based Product Properties are not strongly typed because the type of the Value attribute is fixed and is usually the lowest-common denominator, i.e. text because most values can be represented that way however, it's not possible for Salesforce to tell that the Value of a property named Price is actually of type Currency or Money or Price because its storage type is text.

Clearly there are pros and cons to each depending on

1. How many products there are
2. How widely the products differ from each other.
3. Reporting might be difficult when attributes are key-value pairs.

I'm being pressed to implement Option 3.

I've built a custom page that will build a form out of dynamic apex controls from meta-data stored in as "rows" of a custom object. It works, and data can be saved and edited, but numerous problems are emerging and server-side form building does not look like the right approach.

The main issue is with validation.  The value part of my key-value pair is of type String. I cannot bind InputField components to Strings, only to sObjects. What that means is I cannot leverage the VisualForce framework to render the right kind of control for the type of Product Property and apply validation and mandatory field checking etc. I also don't seem to be able to programmatically set HTML-5 pass-through attributes (prove me wrong). I also don't seem to be able to get direct (dynamic) control of the HTML sent to the browser on the server side.

All this is leading me to think I need to move the dynamic form building on to the client using a combination of AJAX and Angular or Knockout. But doing this introduces a whole other bunch of presentation problems I was conveniently able to avoid by rendering Page Blocks and what not in server side code. How do I maintain the look and feel? Is it documented anywhere how to replicate a Page Block Section or whatever in terms of DOM structure and CSS class attributes, or is that another tough path to follow?

All in all this has led me to question whether modelling using the key-value-type approach for fully flexible attributes is the right way; it certainly seems to have a high price (in terms of not being able to leverage much of the Salesforce infrastructure).

How have you solved modelling Products with completely different properties?

Comment: In the "real world" what you're describing is known as CPQ. Trying to model this Configure, Price, Quote process (on your own) is not a small undertaking and as such there are a number of apps on the AppExchange which attempt to solve this same problem. One very popular package, [Apttus CPQ](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016bGHEAY), uses 21 custom objects to support its very flexible and successful model. It might be advantageous to look into an available app than to try to roll your own.